# Getting time out while running on msmq queue on more application hit

Tags: msmq, msmqintegrationbinding, msmq-transaction

We have batch file for processing the applications through msmq, when the application count is more for ex: 40 at at a time, when it is picking the application in queue, remaining applications are getting time out, as the waiting time for all application is same..

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping up the QMThreadNo registry value to increase the thread pool size.